# Custom Action inner text

Tags: wix

I have the following Wix code,that checks if some registry entry exist it doesn't launch Custom Action.A Question is what is wrong in Custom Action condition defined as inner element?

```
<Property Id="MYSERVER">  
  <RegistrySearch Id="MyServer" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\My Technologies\MyServer" Type="raw" Name="InstallLocation" />  
</Property> 

<CustomAction Id='LaunchMyServer'   BinaryKey="MyServer.exe" ExeCommand="" /> 

<InstallUISequence>


<Custom Action="LaunchMyServer" Before="CostInitialize">MYSERVER>0 </Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the > character in the content. It should be html escaped to &gt;

So try `MYSERVER&gt;0` instead.

Hope it helps.

/Klaus

Answer (score 2):

You have used >, so you have to use a CDATA-block:

```
<Custom Action="LaunchMyServer" Before="CostInitialize"><![CDATA[MYSERVER>0]]> </Custom>
```